# grid element plugin with introcution package typo3

Tags: package, typo3

i am a typo3 newbie. I installted typo3 4.5 with the introduction package.
After i searched whole google, asked people who wrote tutorials about the plugin I am having problems with - i still cannot find a solution. I really hope someone can help me here.

Plugin: Grid Elements

1. I successfully installed the plugin. i edited the main template of the introduction package and included the static template there
2. i created a ne record in my root page with the grid element layout i need. ID of my element is: 3 and i have only 2 columns with ids 20 and 21
3. then i added the conent element on a subpage, inserted my content in my to columns. They successfully appear in the frontend - although with the standard html
   **--> [View CODE](http://content.screencast.com/users/BOEHMCKER/folders/Jing/media/cb1f4bff-79fd-4e36-b41a-295a61129bc7/wrong-html.png)**
4. i also put my TypoScript into the page TSConfig of my "home" root page.
   --> see image below

Some more images to help you understand:
**[View](http://content.screencast.com/users/BOEHMCKER/folders/Jing/media/2a69575c-8cde-456f-85b1-25e6526ef1eb/2012-05-24_0941.png)**

Sorry..not allowed to post images yet ^^

Please tell me what i am doing wrong :)!! Why is my TypoScript not working?

Answer (score 0):

found the problem...
when the indroduction package is installed it is necessary to create a new template element and include the static template here. also the TS should be entered here to display the correct struktur in the frontend

Comment: Thats not right. You should have checked your TS with the `TS Object Browser`.